# Injected scripts in Opera extensions

Tags: javascript, opera, opera-extension

I'm trying to "port" my Chrome-extension to Opera. My extension does nothing else but edits the DOM a little bit. In Chrome extension I use contentscript and based on my research the similar way for Opera is injected scripts. Anyway, [the documentation](http://www.opera.com/docs/apis/extensions/injectedscriptsguide/) doesn't really tell how should I use injected scripts.

I have the js-file in `includes/` but seems like it doesn't include automatically. I also need to specify domains to inject the script on.

Currently my file has this content for testing purposes:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    alert('asd');
});
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: don't forget the third argument to addEventListener() - better make sure it is 'false' ;)

Comment: The 'load' event doesn't bubble. So I think we don't need that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another resource you could read is the [extension tutorial](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/hands-on-building-an-opera-extension/). However, looking at other extensions, I don't think you need to specify anything. Try putting a simple `alert()` in the script, or, even better, try inspecting the runtime with Dragonfly (Ctrl-Shift-I).

Check that you have your `config.xml` and `index.html` in place.